# React native snap carousel no pause between slides

Tags: reactjs, react-native, carousel, react-native-snap-carousel

Sorry for my title, I didn't know how to explain it.
So, I'm using React-native-snap-carousel (3.9.1) on my EXPO application to add a simple carousel.

When I slide between slides, there is no wait / pause. With a fast swipe I can go directly to the last slide.
But I want to make a break between slide and swipe again to go to the next slide.

The problem appear only on my device : Honor 20 / Android 10
I haven't any problem with some others devices like S10, or IOS divices.

Here is my carousel code :

```
<Carousel
    ref={carouselRef}
    keyExtractor={carouselKE}
    data={allSlides}
    sliderWidth={windowWidth}
    itemWidth={windowWidth}
    renderItem={RenderCarouselItem}
    onSnapToItem={(index) => setActiveSlide(index)}
    inactiveSlideOpacity={1}
    inactiveSlideScale={1}
    decelerationRate={5}
/>
```

I tried to use `decelerationRate` without success.

Does anybody got this problem with that lib ?

Thanks

Comment: Also searching for a solution like this. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: No, I didn't find any solutions for that device (Honor 20), but works on others devices. Got problems with some Xiaomi too.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-snap-carousel/v/4.0.0-beta.6

Updated to beta package and fixed the problem. Added disableIntervalMomentum to true

```
<Carousel
    ...
    disableIntervalMomentum={true}
    ... 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think even though I had the same problem with scroll so I added some props in a carousel which solved my issue I think you have a problem with the declarationRate you should reduce it.
`

```
<Carousel
    ref={carouselRef}
    keyExtractor={carouselKE}
    data={allSlides}
    sliderWidth={windowWidth}
    itemWidth={windowWidth}
    renderItem={RenderCarouselItem}
    onSnapToItem={(index) => setActiveSlide(index)}
    inactiveSlideOpacity={1}
    inactiveSlideScale={1}
    lockScrollWhileSnapping={true}
    enableMomentum={false}
    decelerationRate={0.25}
/>
```